# CSS Table long text alignment upon break on table

Tags: css, freemarker

I want to make the header text of my table in the freemarker xml to be centralized but this is what happens:

[image]

My html and CSS is as follows:

```
<table class="itemtable" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='head' align="center" colspan="1"><span class='title_br'>Unbilled Sales Order</span></th>
                        <th class='head' align="center" colspan="1"><span class='title_br'>Job to Date</span></th>
                        <th class='head' align="center" colspan="1"><span class='title_br'>Open PO's</span></th>
                        <th class='head' align="center" colspan="1"><span class='title_br'>Remaining Bdgt. Est. vs. JTD + POs</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
</table>




 table {  
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    font-size: 7pt;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    table-layout: fixed;
                    width: 100%;
                }

table.itemtable td {
                font-size: 7px;
                width: 8%;
            }
            table.itemtable th.head {
                font-size: 6pt;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: black;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-style: solid double solid double ;
            }
span.title_br  {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 7pt;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }
```

Comment: Checked your code in Firefox 43.0.1 and what I see - it's perfectly centralized as you want, so maybe an error is in some other part?

Comment: @kay27 in html this is fine. but when it's in freemarker, this is what happened

Answer (score 0):

Your image looks like there is a `text-align: justify;` setting somewhere in the code. It's not in the code you posted, but judging from the image it has to be somewhere.

Do a search for "justify" and delete that rule if you find it. Maybe it's somewhere in a higher level template or similar...

Comment: there's no justify.  In html this is fine. but when it's in freemarker, this is what happened